# Javascript - get all urls in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking for a clean jquery code which returns urls in a textarea.. I have found some solution but that was not so useful. 
Suppose I have some text :

> I have visited https://jobscane.com and it was so useful for finding
>   jobs in pakistan. and https://google.com helped me to find it.

SO the script should return 2 urls in the string above

What I have tried so far is .

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#textarea").on('keyup', function(){

    const regex = /((?:https?:|www\.)[^\s]+)/g;
    const str = $(this).val();
    let m;

    while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
        m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
        });
    }

     });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well your code can already be simplified a lot by just doing `const matches = str.match(regex);` and then looping over `matches.forEach(m => {console.log(`Found match: ${m}`);});`... but I don't know what you're asking here.

Comment: this code returns me same url twice.. so if I enter 3 urls, the output it shows 6 urls

Comment: If I'm reading your code right you're firing off on `keyup` so it fires on "each" keyup...

Comment: yeah #EdSF ! what should be the best alternative ?

Comment: Depending on your needs, try [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) and the answer below is what you should do.

Comment: Your code is getting it twice because you put the *entire regex* into a capture group. Just remove the outer `()` from your regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can get rid of the `while` and use `match()`

```js
$("textarea").on('keyup', function() {

  const regex = /((?:https?:|www\.)[^\s]+)/g;
  const str = $(this).val();

  let m = str.match(regex);

  if (m) {
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
  }


}).keyup(); // trigger event for demo
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea> I have visited https://jobscane.com and it was so useful for finding
jobs in pakistan. and https://google.com helped me to find it.

</textarea>
```

Comment: @EdSF not sure what you are getting at

Comment: @EdSF oh yeah...not sure what Op wants. Just used their example. Up to them to sort out the event behavior